# How to change UserServicePresence in Salesforce and How to get the list of Status shared to a profile?

Tags: apex, lightning, apexrest, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

I have a requirement to create a Global Quick Action that would display all the "Service Presence Status" available to a Live Agent and Change the status when he selects any of the status available. The agent will use this to go offline or away from his mobile.

the following approach failed :

## 1 Using OmniToolKit -  in my lightning component returns nothing

-Does this work only when added inside service console?

## 2 Using Apex -DML not supported on UserServicePresence

## 3 Using Visualforce - Same issue as OmniToolKit

Now i am trying to

## 4 achieve this via an API callout - but i don't understand how to find the Service Status that is shared with current user`s profile.

Any help to finding the right direction would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update :

Salesforce Support replied that OmniChannelToolKitAPI for Lightning is not supported in Mobile!

The UserServicePresence cannot be changed from anything other than this ToolKit or Javascript API.

Basically, There is no support in mobile!